# replaceAll by function return value [gwt]

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to do something like:

```
calculate(String match) {
    if (match.equals("expr"))
      return "no time";
    else
      return "some time";
}

String text = "You have {expr} or {other} left";
text = text.replaceAll( "{(.+)}", calculate(match) );
```

there the value within curly brackets, like **"expr"**, will somehow be processed in a function **calculate("expr")** and the result will be used as the replacement ? The resulting String should look like this

```
"You have no time or some time left"
```

I know something like this is possible in javascript but I don't know how to do this in GWT

Comment: Would it not be possible to add `text` as an extra parameter to the method `calculate` - then within that method you strip out the expression, process it and return the result?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I edited my question to make it more clear what I was expecting, but thank you anyway

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nMessages.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite what you were looking for, but it should give you the result you're after:

```
public static String calculate( String text )
{
    String regex = "[{][^{]+[}]", replacement = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while ( m.find() )
    {
        String match = m.group();

        if ( "{expr}".equals(match) ) replacement = "X";
        else replacement = "Y";

        text = text.replaceFirst(regex, replacement);
    }

    return text;
}
```

Then to use it:

```
String text = "You have {expr} or {other} left";
System.out.println(calculate(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Java's String-format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). In your example this would be something like so:

```
String text = "You have %s left";
String resultText = String.format(text, calculate(match));
```

Based on the return from calculate, the resultText is either of these two:

```
"You have some time left"
"You have no time left"
```

`%s` is used for Strings. In the link provided you can see a lot of other options available.

You can also use multiple `%-options` in a single String:

```
String text = "You have %s left to do the following task: %s";
String resultText = String.format(text, calculate(match)), "Programming in Java");
// OR
String resultText2 = String.format(text, new String[]{ calculate(match), "Programming in Java" });
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I was expecting. I edited my question, because 'match' should be the found 'expr' or 'other'. Sorry for that confusion